# Editing open Visual Studio files externally: Bad?

Tags: visual-studio

I recently experienced some problems with Visual Studio and wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that I've just started editing documents with another text editor while having the same documents open in Visual Studio.

Anyone know if this causes problems?

Comment: Usually Visual Studio offers to reload the changed files when it notices they have been modified outside of the VS editor. I haven't had any issues with changing files outside of VS so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not. Once you save in the other editor, VS will prompt you if you want to reload the document. You should not have unsaved changes though. The setting to control this behavior can be found in the options (Tools => Options) of Visual Studio.

This screenshot is for VS 2012:

[image]

Comment: I've seen that, but does that mean for sure that VS can handle the changes? Are there any config files that could get corrupted or anything? Thanks.

Comment: VS can handle it. It's built to handle it, after all your source control could potentially write to any file of the solution on update.

Comment: I *believe* that the prompting to reload when changed externally is a setting. Do make sure that setting is turned on if you're going to make a habit of doing this. (You might want to check if I'm right, and add this information to your answer.)